# Tokenize quoted string

Tags: erlang, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize strings. As long as there are no quoting characters all is well:

```
string:tokens ("abc def ghi", " ").
["abc","def","ghi"]
```

But string:tokens/2 does help me much with quoted strings. It behaves as expected:

```
string:tokens ("abc \"def xyz\" ghi", " ").
["abc","\"def","xyz\"","ghi"]
```

What I need is a function that takes a string to be tokenized, a delimiter and a quote character. Something like:

```
tokens ("abc \"def xyz\" ghi", " ", "\"").
["abc","def xyz","ghi"]
```

Now before I start reinventing the wheel, **my question is:**

**Is there such a function or a similar one in the standard libs?**

**EDIT:**

OK, I wrote my own implementation, but I am still highly interested in answers to the original question. Here goes my code so far:

```
tokens (String) -> tokens (String, [], [] ).

tokens ( [], Tokens, Buffer) ->
    lists:map (fun (Token) -> string:strip (Token, both, $") end, Tokens ++ [Buffer] );

tokens ( [Character | String], Tokens, Buffer) ->
    case {Character, Buffer} of
        {$ , [] } -> tokens (String, Tokens, Buffer);
        {$ , [$" | _] } -> tokens (String, Tokens, Buffer ++ [Character] );
        {$ , _} -> tokens (String, Tokens ++ [Buffer], [] );
        {$", [] } -> tokens (String, Tokens, "\"" );
        {$", [$" | _] } -> tokens (String, Tokens ++ [Buffer ++ "\""], [] );
        {$", _} -> tokens (String, Tokens ++ [Buffer], "\"");
        _ -> tokens (String, Tokens, Buffer ++ [Character] )
    end.
```

Comment: Have you considered regexes? It might be one way to do it simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If regular expressions are acceptable in the general case you can use:

```
> re:split("abc \"def xyz\" ghi", " \"|\" ", [{return, list}]).
["abc","def xyz","ghi"]
```

You can also use `"\s\"|\"\s"` if you want to split based on any whitespace instead of just spaces.

If you happen to be parsing this from an input file, you may want to use `strip_split/2` from [estring](https://github.com/dweldon/estring).

Answer (score 2):

`string:tokens ("abc \"def ghi\" foo.bla", " .\"").` will tokenize the string on space, point and double quote. Result: `["abc", "def", "ghi", "foo", "bla"]`. If you want to preserve the quoted parts, you might want to consider creating a Token/Lexer, because regex is not very good at this work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [re](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html) module. It comes with a `split/3` function. For eg :

```
re:split("abc \"def xyz \"ghi", "[(\s\")\s\"]", [{return, list}]).
["abc",[],"def","xyz",[],"ghi"]
```

The second argument is a regular expression (you might have to tweak my example to remove the empty lists...)

Comment: Thank you, but your output (ignoring empty elements) is `["abc","def","xyz","ghi"]`. What I need is with your example `["abc","def xyz ", "ghi"]`. Can this me obtained with your approach?

Comment: That would actually be easier :) `re:split("abc \"def xyz \"ghi", "\s\"", [{return, list}]).`

Comment: However, given the question I expect that you want `tokens("abc def \"def xyz\" ghi", " ", "\"").` to be `["abc", "def", "def xyz", "ghi"]`. With this solution you instead get `["abc def", "def xyz", "ghi"]`.

Comment: @Alexey You are right. I didn't see that. Do you have a simple solution to get this behaviour?

Comment: I didnt quite get the difference.. let me get this straight.. u want a SPECIFIC splitter that splits if delimiter is " ", "\"" OR any sequence of the two ? -OR- do u want a general solution to split based on delimiters given as regex ? (If it is the latter all I just wanted to point you to the re module.. if its the former, I guess you should look at @David Weldon's solution.. it seems like it works)

Comment: I want a function that splits a string on each space, unless this space is inside double quotes. `"abc def ghi"` parses to `["abc", "def", "ghi"]` while `"abc \"def ghi\""` parses to `["abc", "def ghi"]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is approximately how I would write it (not tested!):

```
tokens(String) -> lists:reverse(tokens(String, outside_quotes, [])).

tokens([], outside_quotes, Tokens) ->
  Tokens;
tokens(String, outside_quotes, Tokens) -> 
  {Token, Rest0} = lists:splitwith(fun(C) -> (C != $ ) and (С != $"), String),
  case Rest0 of 
    [] -> [Token | Tokens];
    [$  | Rest] -> tokens(Rest, outside_quotes, [Token | Tokens]);
    [$" | Rest] -> tokens(Rest, inside_quotes, [Token | Tokens])
  end;
tokens(String, inside_quotes, Tokens) -> 
  %% exception on an unclosed quote
  {Token, [$" | Rest]} = lists:splitwith(fun(C) -> С != $", String),
  tokens(Rest, outside_quotes, [Token | Tokens]).
```